# Skeletal Mesh Cloth Simulation bug (UDK), unexpected behaviour

Tags: blender, udk, cloth

When I try to move to the left (A) the pawn *and* the cloth move to the left,
and when I move to the right (D) the pawn *and* the cloth move to the right too...

Why the cloth always goes in *same* direction than the pawn? I would expect the cloth to go in the *opposite* direction, like dragged by the pawn.

To anyone who's experienced with pawn with cloth simulation: please help me T_T

Flag model for testing :
[Flag bug](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rpkzn60fx1ws9r8/flagbug.rar?dl=0)

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
The problem was because I combined the cloth with the pawn. That's why when I move the pawn, the cloth will also move to similar direction too.
I have solve it by **separate the cloth as another object and then attach it to the pawn**..